# Opening a Phones Navigation System from a Mobile Site for Directions?

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone-8

I know when you're searching on google and find and an establishment, (or other apps), you can jus click "get directions" and it will load with google navigation etc. What I'm trying to do is figure out if there's a way to direct a user to an address, and open up the main navigation system on their phone through a mobile site, that will work will all phones (android, iphone windows phone etc)... much like when you click a "call" button and it inputs the phone number into your phones dialing system.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need a slightly different solution for each platform. You could wrap the following logic in a JavaScript function which checks the user agent (or do the check on the server and print a different link).

### iOS

Create a link to **maps.apple.com**

e.g. http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=Cupertino

(Further information: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html)

### Android

Use a **geo** link or link to Google Maps (see below).

geo:0,0?q=San+Francisco+to+Cupertino

(Further information: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps)

### Windows Phone

A Bing URL with the rtp parameter. I haven't been able to test this but there is documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217138.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj635237.aspx

### Everything Else

For every other platform I'd just use a Google Maps link. This is also a possibility for Android as you can make Google Maps links open in the Maps app.

http://maps.google.com/?daddr=San+Francisco&saddr=Cupertino